# Looping through Dictionary object 'variableName' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I'm getting an error that I can't figure out. I tried Google and SO, but to no avail...

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dctConvertedJSON.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dctConvertedJSON(i))
    {
        string strKey = kvp.Key;
        string strValue = kvp.Value;
        Debug.WriteLine("Key: " + strKey.ToString + Constants.vbTab + " Value: " + strValue);
    }
}
```

In the `foreach` I'm getting an error on `dctConvertedJSON` which reads:

`Error: 'dctConvertedJSON' is a 'variable' but is used like a 'method'`

What I am doing (or not doing) to cause this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should correct it to:

```
dctConvertedJSON[i]
```

So the code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dctConvertedJSON.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dctConvertedJSON[i])
    {
        string strKey = kvp.Key;
        string strValue = kvp.Value;
        Debug.WriteLine("Key: " + strKey.ToString() + Constants.vbTab + " Value: " + strValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh!! That's what I get for being a VB developer for so many years!! Thank you